# How do get numbers to display as two digits in C?

Tags: c, digit

For C programming. How do i get numbers to be displayed as 00, 01, 02, 03, instead of 0, 1, 2, 3. I just need 0 before the number until 10.

i know when your doing decimals you can do "%.2f" etc. but what about in reverse for integers?

here is what I am using...**

```
printf("Please enter the hours: ");
    scanf ("%d",&hour);
printf("Please enter the minutes: ");
    scanf ("%d",&minute);
printf("Please enter the seconds: ");
    scanf ("%d",&second);
printf("%d : %d : %d\n", hour, minute, second);
```

}

I need the numbers to display as 00 : 00 : 00

??

Comment: Has to be a dupe, right?

Answer (score 91):

You need to use `%02d` if you want leading zeroes padded to two spaces:

```
printf ("%02d : %02d : %02d\n", hour, minute, second);
```

See for example the following complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int hh = 3, mm = 1, ss = 4, dd = 159;
    printf ("Time is %02d:%02d:%02d.%06d\n", hh, mm, ss, dd);
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
Time is 03:01:04.000159
```

---

Keep in mind that the `%02d` means two characters *minimum* width so it would output 123 *as* `123`. That shouldn't be a problem if your values are valid hours, minutes and seconds, but it's worth keeping in mind because many inexperienced coders seem to make the mistake that 2 is somehow the minimum *and* maximum length.

Comment: what is the solution for tuning the maximum  length?

Comment: @rahman, there's no good solution for specifying maximum length. If you have the value `123` and you shoehorn it into two digits, you'll get one of `12` or `23`, depending on how you decide to do it. Neither of those is acceptable in my opinion. Far better to output `**` as an indication that something's gone horribly wrong.

Comment: This also works for hexa printf("%02X", ... );

Answer (score 45):

Use the format: `%02d` instead. The `0` means to pad the field using zeros and the `2` means that the field is two characters wide, so for any numbers that take less than 2 characters to display, it will be padded with a 0.

Answer (score 7):

`"%.2d"` is what should be used.
The rule is basically;

`"%<minimum-characters-overall>.<minimum-digits>d"`.

For example:

`"%6.3d"` will print 6 characters overall and a minimum of 3 digits.